# can't push after rest hard - everything up to date

Tags: git

After I commited, I changed my code but I didn't want to keep the changes, so I did a rest hard
`git reset -hard 29920a13b3563b8` to my last commit.

Then, I made some new changes, commit and when I tried to push , git shows that everything is up to date.

I then tried `git remote set-head origin master` and now I have a situation :

```
commit dd0238f3f02986a82078191e04378487b327cfd0 (HEAD)
Author:...
Date:   Thu May 6 18:07:09 2021 +0300

    My newest commit 

commit 29920a13b3563b8df16da91de452fea936be9c5a (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
Author: ...
Date:   Wed May 5 15:53:50 2021 +0300

    My last commit

commit cd21723ca691e1269e8bac318ec16cf076e24b21
Author: ....
Date:   Wed May 5 11:13:52 2021 +0300

    Older commit
```

1. where the HEAD is at another commit from origin/HEAD
2. with the `set-head origin master` , origin/master was created! ( I had only origin/HEAD)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `git log` output shows that you are in *detached HEAD* mode.  This means you need to *save the commit hash ID* of the commit where you are right now, just in case, using a new branch or tag name.  For instance:

```
git branch save-this
```

will create a new branch name to remember `dd0238f3f02986a82078191e04378487b327cfd0`.  (Unless you have Git remember this for you, you will have to memorize enough of this string of letters and digits to reconstruct it later.)

Next, use `git status` to see if you are in the middle of some operation that put you *in* this mode.  If so, complete (finish) or terminate (e.g., `git rebase --abort`) the operation as appropriate and you will probably be out of this mode.  If not—or if completing or aborting the operation still leaves you *in* detached-HEAD mode—use `git checkout master` to get back to branch `master`.  This leaves you with commit `dd0238f3f02986a82078191e04378487b327cfd0` *not* on `master`, which is why we made a name to remember that big ugly hash ID.

You can now try to add the new commit *to* `master` directly:

```
git merge --ff-only save-this
```

which will *fast-forward* your `master` to the commit, if that's possible.  (It probably is, based on your `git log` output here, although I can't be sure because I cannot see the specific `git log` command you ran.)  If this works, you will now be able to run:

```
git push origin master
```

to send this new commit to the other Git repository and ask that Git repository to update its `master`.  If all that has worked, it's now time to delete the no-longer-needed name `save-this`, using:

```
git branch -d save-this
```

If something goes wrong during this process, well, we'll come back to that if/when it happens.

Comment: Thanks!It works fine now! I have in my last commit now `(HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)`. Is this ok? I mean, I don't remember if I had both `origin/master` , `origin/HEAD` .

Comment: It's normal: `origin/HEAD` is your Git's way of remembering which branch is your "main" one from `origin`, `origin/master` is your Git's way of remembering "where their `master` was, last time I saw it", and `HEAD -> master` is `git log`'s way of saying that you're on your own `master`. All three names now identify the same commit by hash ID, which is what we were hoping for. :-)

Comment: :Hmm..we have a problem! After that, I made some commits and now , when trying to push, I am falling again into the same situation! HEAD is at the last commit and  `(HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)`, is at the commit where I did the last push! So, it seems the solution is not permanent!

Comment: If you have `HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD` as the decorations on your *current* commit, *your* Git thinks—at this point—that your `master` is completely in sync with `origin`'s `master`. Run `git fetch origin` to update your Git's view of `origin`'s Git repository, in case that's out of date; if they're all still in sync like this, you've successfully pushed any commits you made on your own `master` already, and whatever problem you are having is not caused by failure to push.

Comment: :No, `HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master` is at a previous commit when I have pushed. From there, on I made 2 more commits, and now I want to push. My last commit now shows the `HEAD` and my previous 2 commits (when I pushed), shows (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)

Comment: I tried, `git fetch origin ` but still the same

Comment: `HEAD -> master` means you're on `master` right now (`git status` will say `on branch master`). Moreover, `git log` with no arguments starts at the *current commit*. Why do you think you have other commits than the ones being shown? Where did you make them?

Comment: Sorry, I saw that in my comment 1 hour above, I say `(HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)`, but its wrong. The right one is at my last comment `(origin/master, origin/HEAD, callisto/master, master)`

Comment: Aha. Where is *your* `HEAD` then? That's the key. You're not *on* your `master` branch. What branch *are* you on? Are you on *any* branch? What does `git status` say about which branch is your current branch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232417/discussion-between-george-and-torek).